# Having Issue on Field Calculator With Python in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I have tried all of below snippets to use Python Parser in Field Calculator and update the values of a field called `type` based on a filed called `MamerMN` but in all of them I am getting Syntax error in Geoprocessing result window!

```
if !MamerMN! <= 0.151560:
    return 1
```

and

```
if (!MamerMN! <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

and

```
if (MamerMN <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

and

```
def(MamerMN)
if MamerMN <= 0.151560:
    return 1
```

and

```
def(MamerMN)
if (MamerMN <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your functions wrong. In the Field Calculator, make sure you check 'Show Codeblock' so the **Pre-Logic Script Code** box appears. Inside the Pre-Logic box, write your function-

```
def calcValue(mamerMN):
    if mamerMN <= 0.151560:
        return 1
```

and then in the box under, where it says the *field_name* =
you should write the name of the function and the field value you are passing to it surrounded by exclamations. So if your function above is named calcValue you would write

```
calcValue(!mamerMN!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a graphic of what your Field Calculator looks like, I suspect @csterling is probably right. However, an alternative is to just [Select by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) where `"mamerMN" <= 0.151560`, then [Field Calculate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) your selected features to 1 the regular way without necessitating a codeblock.